# C# listbox Collection syntax

Tags: c#, linq, collections, listbox, ienumerable

While learning C# pretty fast, I am stumbling on this Collection syntax problem.

I added a number of objects of my own type MyItem to listbox lstData. Now I need to search in this listbox and thought of using the elegant LINQ notation like:

```
lstData.Items.Where(x => x.Text == SearchString)
```

but the Items of a listbox does not have a .Where(), although I did include the "using System.Linq;" namespace.

So I tried:

```
foreach (MyItem item in (MyItem)lstData.Items)
```

but this gives the build error: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' to 'MySandbox.frmListboxDemo.MyItem'.

I did manage to write something workable:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lstData.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            MyItem item = (MyItem)lstData.Items[i];
            if (item.Text == SearchString)
            {
                lstData.SetSelected(i, true);
                break;
            }
        }
```

and a similar version like:

```
        var item_enum = lstData.Items.GetEnumerator();
        while (item_enum.MoveNext()) { etc etc... }
```

which turned out to be 2 lines longer, and without figuring what could replace 'var'.

I am not really sure I understand how to use Collections, ObjectCollections, Enumerators etc, but am eager to learn. Especially if a .Where() version is possible and/or better.

---

Thanks for all your answers. I ended up with this solution:

```
        var item_iter = lstData.Items.Cast<MyItem>()
                          .Where(x => x.Text.Trim().ToLower() == txtItemName.Text);
        foreach (MyItem item in item_iter)
        {
            int i = lstData.Items.IndexOf(item);
            lstData.SetSelected(i, true);
            break;
        }
```

I don't know if this is really much better than the "fortran" way (see above), but it does teach me methods I can use in other C# queries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the `Cast<T>` first to perform a cast to the type you expect it to be. That is:

`lstData.Items.Cast<MyItem>().Where(x => x.Text == SearchString)`

Comment: The error is now: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast<TResult>(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @Roland Sorry, I forgot the `()` to call it. (I was going to fix things up and add more as @Jan did, but got called away)

Comment: Chris, thanks for your help. I found the () myself after some reflection. I got this to work. Now I just have to read all other comments for interesting points.

Answer (score 20):

The items collection is no strongly typed collection. You can use the `IEnumerable<T>.OfType()` or `IEnumerable<T>.Cast()` extension methods to get the entry to the LINQ world where you can filter your entries:

```
var filteredItems = lstData.Items.OfType<MyItem>().Where(i => i.Prop == val);
```

The difference between Cast and OfType is:

- `OfType<T>` will just return the items which are castable to Type T
- `Cast<T>` will fail, when at least one item is in the collection which is not castable to T

Comment: Perfect answer.. one small thing though, it's necessary to have the () brackets after OfType - OfType<MyItem>().Where(...

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.ObjectCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, but not the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, which most Linq methods require.

One way to get to `IEnumerable<T>` AND solve your casting issue in one step is to use `Cast<T>`:

```
lstData.Items.Cast<MyItem>().Where(x => x.Text == SearchString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a list out of the items:

```
(new ListBox()).Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Where(......);
```

Probably the reason is because it was originally built with earlier version of .net